# Is there any way to read a pdf using AS3? (Air)

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, mobile, air

I want to be able to read at least some of the info a pdf has, this is in mobile, using an installed app built with Air.

Are there any libraries or methods to do this?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is through `StageWebView` if you are running iOS. On Android, I haven't really found a good way to do it. There are no good libraries for it. Almost every PDF-related AS3 library is focused on writing PDFs, not displaying them. I've found a few in the past that can display them, but the end result is terrible and slow.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, what I want is to parse the pdf, I mean, I want to be able to extract for example an xml that is inside that pdf. Is that possible?.